# aframe in cordova on an Samsung S7 (Gear-VR)

Tags: android, cordova, aframe, phonegap, gear-vr

I use a-frame to display a Videosphere on an Android Samsung S7.

It works fine on Chrome. However if I package the whole thing as an App using Cordova the perspective (and the eye "pieces") are displayed wrong (see attachment).

Chrome (correct version)
[image: Chrome (correct version)]

Cordova (distorted version)
[image: on Cordova (distorted version)]

What can I do to have the same rendering in my Cordova app as in Chrome?

Comment: I get this on any aframe scene on my S7 & S8 using chrome & samsung browsers. You could try project crosswalk, apparently it uses a different webview to cordova. There is also a crosswalk plugin if you want to use cordova with the crosswalk webview - https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I tried that already though, and unfortunately the result is exactly the same.

Comment: I managed to fix this on my S8. It was related to this issue - https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2857
Try changing your resolution to WQHD (2560 x 1440).

Comment: I'm interested to hear if this worked as I'm planning to deploy aframe via crosswalk/cordova.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. The resolution was set to WQHD already. Changing it does not make a difference either. It actually looks like it could be related to https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2857 But it did not help me to find a solution.